# Is there a definition of all the implicit parameters in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Blazor has the implicit parameters Context and ChildContent. Are there other implicit parameters (or properties or …)?

And is there a listing that explains what each is, when/how to use it, etc.?

And where does each come from? IComponent & ComponentBase, as best as I can tell, don’t have any parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And where does each come from?

They are handled and inserted by the Razor compiler.

I think your list (of 2) is pretty much complete.
It's possible to rename `context`.